# Unwanted behavior by Python List of Lists

Tags: python

I am trying to represent a matrix as a list of lists and populate it with values based on weather the position in the matrix satisfies some conditions. The variable I am storing it in is `self._solution`.

In order to proceed I am taking 2 different approaches:
**Approach 1:**

```
def __init__(self, N=3, puzzle=None):
        self.N = N
        self.SIZE = self.N*self.N
        self.puzzle = [[set([1])]*(self.SIZE)]*(self.SIZE)
        if puzzle is None:
            for i in range(self.SIZE):
                self.puzzle[i] = [int(k) for k in raw_input()]
        else:
            self.puzzle = [[int(k) for k in line] for line in puzzle.splitlines()]

        self._empty_cells = 0    
        self._solutions = [[0]*(self.SIZE)]*(self.SIZE)
        self._solutions = []
        print self.puzzle
        print self._solutions
        for i in range(self.SIZE):
            self._solutions.append([])
            for j in range(self.SIZE):
                if self.puzzle[i][j] < 1:
                    #self._solutions[i][j] = set(range(1,self.SIZE+1))
                    self._solutions[i].append(1)
                    self._empty_cells += 1
                    print "puzzle[%s][%s] = %s\tsolutions[%s][%s] = %s" % (i,j, self.puzzle[i][j], i, j, self._solutions[i][j])
                else:
                    self._solutions[i].append(0)
        print self._solutions
```

**Approach 2:**

```
def __init__(self, N=3, puzzle=None):
        self.N = N
        self.SIZE = self.N*self.N
        self.puzzle = [[set([1])]*(self.SIZE)]*(self.SIZE)
        if puzzle is None:
            for i in range(self.SIZE):
                self.puzzle[i] = [int(k) for k in raw_input()]
        else:
            self.puzzle = [[int(k) for k in line] for line in puzzle.splitlines()]

        self._empty_cells = 0    
        self._solutions = [[0]*(self.SIZE)]*(self.SIZE)
        #self._solutions = []
        print self.puzzle
        print self._solutions
        for i in range(self.SIZE):
            #self._solutions.append([])
            for j in range(self.SIZE):
                if self.puzzle[i][j] < 1:
                    #self._solutions[i][j] = set(range(1,self.SIZE+1))
                    self._solutions[i][j] = 1
                    #self._solutions[i].append(1)
                    self._empty_cells += 1
                    print "puzzle[%s][%s] = %s\tsolutions[%s][%s] = %s" % (i,j, self.puzzle[i][j], i, j, self._solutions[i][j])
        print self._solutions
```

What I am considered is how the value of `self._solution` is set. Ideally both the approaches should work best however the output of the 2 approaches differs significantly. I would want only the positions which satisfy the condition `self.puzzle[i][j] == 0` to be set to 1. However, in Approach 2 all the values of `self._solution` are set to 1, whereas Approach 1 works correctly.

Also in Approach 2 if I just add an else block after the `if self.puzzle[i][j] == 0` condition and then set the value of `self._solution[i][j] = 0` then the output is correct.

Can anyone explain this weird behavior. Has anyone else also seen similar results.

I am using iPython and Python 2.7

Edit: It is not a duplicate of [unexpected behaviour of nested lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703303) as this one deals with the * operator as pointed out by @Crazy Casta. Also I figured out that the case where I have something like this:
`self._solutions = [[set([])]*SIZE]*SIZE` is even more dangerous as each created set element points to the same element in the memory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unexpected behaviour of nested lists in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703303/unexpected-behaviour-of-nested-lists-in-python)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I have to disagree. Nothing in that question relates to the * operator on lists, which is what the trouble is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot to take in, but I'm guessing you're having trouble with this bit:

```
self._solutions = [[0]*(self.SIZE)]*(self.SIZE)
```

Assuming that what you're trying to do is make `self.SIZE` independent lists of size `self.SIZE` then you're not getting what you want. The list multiplication syntax that you're using copies the reference, and therefore you have a list of `self.SIZE` references to the same list. What you want is:

```
self._solutions = [[0]*(self.SIZE) for _ in range(self.SIZE)]
```

This will create a new list `self.SIZE` times instead of reusing the same one.